# Is it possible to use React without outputting HTML?

Tags: reactjs, webview, react-native, television

Is it possible to use React or React Native to build on embedded devices as well as the web, such as Samsung Smart TVs, Kindle devices etc.

Perhaps outputting HTML for Web, but something like XML for other devices.

Comment: React Native does not render html. It renders native UI components for ios/Android.

Comment: But are there ways to render native UI components for other devices?

Answer (score 0):

React Native, by default, renders to:

- The web
- Android
- iOS

But, with things like [react-tv](https://medium.com/@raphamorim/developing-for-tvs-with-react-tv-b5b5204964ef), [react-ape](https://github.com/raphamorim/react-ape), and [RN For Windows (which can render to MacOS and Xbox too)](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/), the possiblities are endless.